# Adaptive Trigger doesn't back to initial state after a breakpoint

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I have created an adaptive triggers with two different views. All Setters works fine when program is started independently from the resolution, but after resizing when we reach a breakpiont there is a problem with a proper arrangement. This confuse me.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SmallScreen">
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BigScreen">
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Pivot Title="Pivot">
        <PivotItem Header="Head">
            <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="ImgPanel">
                <Image x:Name="Image" Source="/Assets/someImage.jpg" Width="200" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTxt" Text="Title" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18.667" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="TextPanel">
                    <Rectangle Height="32" Fill="#C33D27" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="Place for long text" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </PivotItem>
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "but after resizing when we reach a breakpiont there is a problem with a proper arrangement"? I just tested your xaml code, the adaptive layout worked well after resizing, could you show us some screenshots?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT
[1. Initial state](http://i.imgur.com/GL53Sb3.jpg) -  works fine 
[2. Stretching an window](http://i.imgur.com/KE9Y7bZ.jpg) - still good
[3. Back to initial size of window](http://i.imgur.com/s5R29Pk.jpg) - setters doesn't apply properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because those two VisualStates are in two different VisualStateGroups. Each VisualStateGroup can have one VisualState active, so this means that in your case **both VisualStates get active** at the same time.

At first, only the MinWindowWidth VisualState is active. When you resize the window, that activates the second VisualState. To fix it, make sure that those VisualStates are in the same VisualStateGroup.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SmallScreen">
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Target="ImgPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Target="TextPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```